# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'childNode')

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

hi I am trying to follow the below tutorial for my formset only i find problem in part:

**container.insertBefore (newForm, addButton)**

and the error that presents me is the following:

**calculos.js: 195 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'childNode')**

I've already tried everything but can't find the childNode

> JS

```js
let parteForm = document.querySelectorAll(".part-form")
let container = document.querySelector("#part-form-container")
let addButton = document.querySelector("#add-form")
let totalForms = document.querySelector("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS")
let formNum = parteForm.length-1 // Get the number of the last form on the page with zero-based indexing


addButton.addEventListener('click', addForm)

function addForm(){
    //e.preventDefault()
    let newForm = parteForm[0].cloneNode(true)
    let formRegex = RegExp(`form-(\\d){1}-`,'g')
    formNum++
    newForm.innerHTML = newForm.innerHTML.replace(formRegex, `form-${formNum}-`)

    container.insertBefore(newForm, addButton)

    //parentnode.insertbefore(newnode,elnodoantesdelcualseinsertanewnode)
    //#part-form-container.insertbefore(div.part-form,)

    totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formNum+1}`)
}
```

> HTML

```
<form method="POST" id="part-form-container">
{% csrf_token %}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
   <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row mb-3">
                   <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                       <label for="verticalnav-email-input">Summary</label>                                                               
                     {{presupuestosparteform.resumen}}

                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>


<h4 class="card-title">Parts list</h4>
<p class="card-title-desc">Add the parts that you need to include.</p>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-success mb-4" id="add-form" onclick="addForm()" value="+ Add part" />
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered table-nowrap align-middle" id="childTable1">
                                                                                
<tbody>
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
<div class="part-form">
        <tr>
           <td>
                                                                                        
                   {{form.codigo}}

                    </td>
                     <td>
                                                                                        
                   {{form.descripcion}}

                  </td>

                 </tr>
               </div>
             {% endfor %}

           </tbody>
       </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You've got `container.insertBefore(newForm, addButton)` - that will only work if `addButton` is a direct child of `container`, and it's not.  There are a bunch of unclosed divs which aren't helping.

Comment: thank you! it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your code but to me seems that some closing "div" tags are missing. My suggestion is to reorganize your code and clean it.

### Now for what concern the bug

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore):

> The insertBefore() method of the Node interface inserts a node before
> a reference node as a child of a specified parent node.

You just have to make sure that the cointer contains the element you want to insert before, so i think that just closing open div tags will solve.
I also noticed that there is no element with Id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS", so the setAttribute can't work.

```js
let parteForm = document.querySelectorAll(".part-form")
let container = document.querySelector("#part-form-container")
let addButton = document.querySelector("#add-form")
let totalForms = document.querySelector("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS")
let formNum = parteForm.length-1 // Get the number of the last form on the page with zero-based indexing


addButton.addEventListener('click', addForm)

function addForm(){
    //e.preventDefault()
    let newForm = parteForm[0].cloneNode(true)
    let formRegex = RegExp(`form-(\\d){1}-`,'g')
    formNum++
    newForm.innerHTML = newForm.innerHTML.replace(formRegex, `form-${formNum}-`)

    container.insertBefore(newForm, addButton)

    //parentnode.insertbefore(newnode,elnodoantesdelcualseinsertanewnode)
    //#part-form-container.insertbefore(div.part-form,)
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="part-form-container">



                <label for="verticalnav-email-input">Summary</label>


          <h4 class="card-title">Parts list</h4>
          <p class="card-title-desc">Add the parts that you need to include.</p>

          <input type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-success mb-4" id="add-form" onclick="addForm()" value="+ Add part" />
          
<tbody>
  <div class="part-form">
          <tr>
             <td>Data-1</td>
             <td>Data-2</td>
          </tr>
  </div>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: ok I just checked my code, you're right, I had a div that shouldn't be there. I also fixed the insertbefore(), the problem that I now see is that when I click if the number changes, however, no new form appears, perhaps it is what you mention that I am missing: Id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS", so the setAttribute; but isn't it my totalForms variable that does it? How can I implement it so that the setAttribute works

Comment: I'm sorry, it's too hard for me to help you in this way. I suggest you open a now question explaining in detail your problem with a live example of your code. Surely someone will help you.